# How to check if mongoose is connected?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

In a project I am working on, I connect to a database like so and it outputs the console.log part

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const expressServer = app.listen(3001);
const io = socketio(expressServer);

const Game = require('./Models/Game')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', 
                        {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},
                        ()=>{console.log('successfully connected to database')});
```

Later on, I created a schema model with mongoose, created an instance of this model and when I try to save it on line 13, the code stops executing when it reaches this point.

```
1    io.on('connect', (socket)=>{
2        socket.on('create-game',async (nickName)=>{
3            try{
4                const quotableData = await QuotableAPI();
5                let game = new Game();
6                game.words = quotableData;
7                let player = {
8                    socketID : socket.id,
9                    isPartyLeader : true,
10                    nickName
11                }
12                game.players.push(player);
13                game = await game.save();
14                .......
```

So I was wondering whether it may be that I am not connected to the database. For reference, I tried

```
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)
```

and it outputed 0, which I saw in other posts means that you are not connected. If this is the case, how would one resolve this problem.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2280

Comment: Does your code '()=>{console.log('successfully connected to database')' actually print the message?

Comment: Yes, it actually prints the message in my console.

Comment: To chewie, when I try this, I get a MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: Update: Installing MongoDB locally solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could verify the same by printing the all the collections from the connected database.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const expressServer = app.listen(3001);
const io = socketio(expressServer);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
    console.log('Connected to mongo server.');

    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names);
    });
})
```

Comment: When I try this, I get ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 ```

Comment: This worked for me using my Atlas connection.

`mongodb+srv://${mongoClient.username}:${mongoClient.password}@${mongoClient.url}/${mongoClient.database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: Callback style async code will not be "awaited", so you might wanna check promisify the toArray function https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original and catch this unhandled exception within the context of `on("open")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mongoose.connection.connect` to check.

```
const mongoClient = require('./config/default')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// MongoDB

mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb+srv://${mongoClient.username}:${mongoClient.password}@${mongoClient.url}/${mongoClient.database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
)

// Test connection
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
  console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully')
})
```

Is your local mongodb server running?

In terminal type `mongod` to start it.

You can also use Mongo Compass to check it.

[Here is a good article on it.](https://zellwk.com/blog/local-mongodb/)